# Square Payment API - Issue with smaller denomination of amount

Tags: node.js, square

I am using Square Payment API, I couldn't find anything in documents for the same,

Let say I want to charge 52.50 CAD.

As we all know It does not allow decimal amount (I am using Node.js SDK v2).

When I go through the documentation it says that amount must be in the smaller denomination.

I have own custom form, I want to know, do I need to pass amount in smaller denomination when the passing value from payment form (generating card nonce), or only in the API side, or both.

I am asking amount from the user without smaller denomination i.e. (52.50 CAD), How do I pass amount in SDK and in the frontend as well.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest denomination of the Canadian Dollar (CAD), like the US Dollar (USD), is cents.

Your custom/front-end form may elect to show the amount in dollars, but the API call must be in the smallest denomination.

As you can see in the below example code, the nonce is taken from the payment form and the charged amount is hard coded. If you wanted to take the charged amount from the form, you would need to **sanitize it**, convert it to cents (if in dollars) and make sure that the currency ID is correct.

### Example Code

Source: [Payment processing example: Node JS](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/master/connect-examples/v2/node_payment/routes/index.js#L18-L47)

```
router.post('/process-payment', function(req,res,next){
  var request_params = req.body;

  var idempotency_key = require('crypto').randomBytes(64).toString('hex');

  // Charge the customer's card
  var transactions_api = new squareConnect.TransactionsApi();
  var request_body = {
    card_nonce: request_params.nonce,
    amount_money: {
      amount: 100, // $1.00 charge
      currency: 'USD'
    },
    idempotency_key: idempotency_key
  };
  transactions_api.charge(config.squareLocationId, request_body).then(function(data) {
    console.log(util.inspect(data, false, null));
    res.render('process-payment', {
      'title': 'Payment Successful',
      'result': "Payment Successful (see console for transaction output)"
    });
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(util.inspect(error.status, false, null));
    res.render('process-payment', {
      'title': 'Payment Failure',
      'result': "Payment Failed (see console for error output)"
    });
  });

});
```

### Relevant documentation:

- [`SquareConnect.TransactionsApi`](https://github.com/square/connect-javascript-sdk/blob/HEAD/docs/TransactionsApi.md#charge)
- [`SquareConnect.ChargeRequest`](https://github.com/square/connect-javascript-sdk/blob/HEAD/docs/ChargeRequest.md)
- [`SquareConnect.Money`](https://github.com/square/connect-javascript-sdk/blob/HEAD/docs/Money.md)

Comment: Do I need to pass amount in the smaller denomination in frontend form as well?

Comment: As stated above, the form is of your design. You can do as you wish. I personally would not put the price into the form, as any savvy person could just change the price at will to be free or $0.01. Instead, I would have a list of products in a database, calculate the cost based on their cart, show it to the user and collect their payment information. Then on the backend, charge the user for the products they have selected and process their order.